# Mercurial Error 10061 only on some branches

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using a very large Mercurial repository. I have done a clean clone of the repository.

When I try to update to the latest revision of the "default" branch I get the following error:

> Error 10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it.

After much trial and error I have found that branches whose ancestor is rev 1000 give me this error.

However, branches whose ancestor is rev 999 do not give me this error and I can update to them just fine.

Others who use this repository do not seem to have this issue.

I have done searches, but most people who get this error are having proxy or connection issues. I wouldn't think I have either of these issues because I can clone and update to some branches just fine.

What is causing this?

#### Edit

I have updated to the latest version of Tortoise-Hg with the same results.

Comment: Are there any big files (added, maybe heavy-edited) in problematic trees?

Comment: Yes, there are heavy edited files in the problematic trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I had a conflict of hgrc files.

The main project hgrc file had a default path address that could be accessed outside the company. A submodule had an hgrc file with a default path address that could only be accessed within the company subnet.

For some reason the conflict of addresses didn't allow me to update, even if I was using VPN to access the company subnet.

The submodule was added at rev 1000. Which is why I could do updates with revs below 1000 or branches that didn't have rev 1000 merged in.

By changing both hgrc files to use the same default path address that can be seen outside the company subnet fixed the issue.